# How to check if the n'th letter in a string is non-zero

Tags: python, buffer-overflow

I need to check of the n'th letter in a string is non-zero.
The code will be used to check if an input to a buffer will overflow the auth variable stored right after the buffer.

```
def test(expect, ans):
    try:
        return len(str(ans)) >= int(expect) and ans[10] is not False
    except ValueError:
        return False


def test2(expect, ans):
    try:
        return len(str(ans)) >= int(expect) and ans[15] != 0
    except ValueError:
        return False


ans1 = "asdfghjklp0"
print(ans1[10])
print(test(11, ans1))
ans2 = "1234567890123450"
print(ans2[15])
print(test2(16, ans2))
```

Both tests should return false.

Comment: `ans[i]` is `str`, not `int`. Use `!= 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

```py
def iszero_nth_letter(s, n=10):
    ss = s[n]
    # check if the n-th letter is a digit and 0 as well
    decision = ss.isdigit() and int(ss)==0
    return decision

print(iszero_nth_letter(s=ans1, n=10))
print(iszero_nth_letter(s=ans2, n=15))
print(iszero_nth_letter(s=ans2, n=13))
```

**Output**:

```
True
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

This working for me:

```
def test(expect, ans):
    return ans[expect-1] != "0"


ans1 = "asdfghjklp0"
print(ans1[10])
print(test(11, ans1))

ans2 = "1234567890123450"
print(ans2[15])
print(test(16, ans2))
```